# Is it possible to add Adobe PDF as a printer in Lion?

Tags: printing, pdf

I want to add Adobe PDF as a printer in Lion.

I know how to use the "pdf" button in the print dialog, but that unfortunately won't work for the task I have in mind.

Does anyone know how to this?

I'm an Adobe Creative Cloud subscriber so have access to the latest version of Acrobat.

Alternatively, does anyone know if its possible to add a different, not-necessarily-Adobe PDF printer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After installing Acrobat, there should be an Adobe PDF entry in the list of printers (System Settings -> Printers).

Alternatively, you can try [CUPS-PDF](https://bitbucket.org/codepoet/cups-pdf-for-mac-os-x/wiki/Home)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in Snow Leopard or later.

From [Adobe's support site](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/cant-print-pdfs-mac-os.html):

> The Adobe PDF Printer is not available or is unusable in Mac OS X Snow Leopard (v10.6). This situation is due to security features in Snow Leopard that disable the Adobe PDF Printer. Adobe Acrobat 9.1 Pro removes the Adobe PDF Printer and adds a new Save As Adobe PDF command.

Comment: That is super lame but thanks for the answer.